# Control vertices of nonparametric Bézier curve $y = 2x –2x^2$

Tags: bezier-curve

My teacher solved this problem, but I don't know how he get that the:
 $$y_0-2y_1+y_2 = -2$$
$$-2y_0 + 2y_1 = 2$$
$$y_0 = 0$$

Here is the full example with solution, step by step:

$$y=2x-2x^2$$
$$y=2t-2t^2$$
$$y(t)=y_0 (1-t)^2+ y_1 2(1-t)t+y_2 t^2$$
$$y(t)=y_0 -2y_0+t^2 y_0+ 2ty_1-2t^2 y_1+y_2 t^2$$
$$y(t)=y_0 -2y_0+t^2 y_0+ 2ty_1-2t^2 y_1+y_2 t^2$$

$$y_0=0$$

$$-2y_0+2y_1=2$$
$$2y_1=2$$
$$y_1=1$$

$$y_0-2y_1+y_2=-2$$
$$-2+y_2=-2$$
$$y_2=0$$
$$V_0=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},V_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},V_2=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two expressions for $y(t)$:
$$
y(t) = y_0 - 2y_0 + t^2 y_0 + 2ty_1 - 2t^2 y_1 + y_2 t^2
$$
and
$$
y(t) = 2t - 2t^2
$$
The first one can be re-arranged to give:
$$
y(t) = -y_0 + (2y_1)t + (y_0 - 2y_1 + y_2)t^2
$$
For this polynomial to be identical with the second one (i.e. for the two curves to be the same), the coefficients of corresponding powers of $t$ must be equal. So
\begin{align}
\text{Coefficients of } t^0 \; &: \quad -y_0 = 0  \\
\text{Coefficients of } t   \; &: \quad 2y_1 = 2  \\
\text{Coefficients of } t^2 \; &: \quad y_0 - 2y_1 + y_2 = -2  \\
\end{align}

Comment: There shouldn't be a - sign? $$y_0-2y_1+y_2 $$

Comment: You're right. I fixed it. Thanks.